# How to get Ajax to return values from previous request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, for-loop, append

I am attempting to append text (a value in a previously created array) to a DIV in each iteration below.  The Ajax call seems to be waiting to return its output until all iterations are complete.

Is there a way to append during each iteration?

Thanks.

```
var inputValue = [];

$("form#null_form :input[type=text]").each(function () {
    inputValue.push($(this).prop('value'));
});

for (var i = 1; i < inputValue.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://urlthatdoessomething.xxx",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (output_string) {
            $('#results').append('<p class=\"normal-msg\">' + inputValue[i] + ' column successfully converted...</p> ');
        },
        error: function (output_string) {
            $('#results').append('<p class=\"error-msg\">ERROR:  Check spelling and try again... </p> ');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: AJAX inside a `for` -- can be dangerous. If the server is down, you're sending a lot of requests to a dead end!

Comment: Plus there is no guarantee that you will get them appended in the order of ajax call made.

Comment: Seems strange, you're not sending anything to the server, and you're not getting anything back that you actually use, and you send an ajax request for each input in the matching forms? What exactly is the ajax request doing, and what do you expect to have it output. As a sidenote, you'll need a closure to keep the value of `i` constant in the async callback

Comment: @tymeJV - This routine is in the backend of a site and will get used very infrequently.  The number of items the Ajax call needs to work on varies, which is why I currently have it in a loop.  Is there a **better** way to accomplish this?  Open to suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo - The routine does make change in an external database.  I just didn't include the specifics in the example.

Comment: @user3062929 -- A recursive call is always the way I like to go, wait for one request to complete, in the callback, fire off another *if* there is one

Comment: ^^^ and that would generally look something like -> http://jsfiddle.net/J3dGE/

Comment: Thanks @ademeo.  Much better alternative.  Will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is by definition asynchronous.  This means that your code does not wait for the response from `http://urlthatdoessomething.xxx` before proceeding in the for loop.  Effectively, the for loop quickly makes all the AJAX requests and as the responses come in, the text is appended.  The iterations have already happened, so close in time together in fact, that the responses seem to all come back at the same time and all the text seems to be appended at the same time.

The solution to this problem is to call the next request in the callback of the AJAX function rather than with a for loop.  This way the next request will not be executed until the previous one was fulfilled, giving you the time that you expected between iterations.

```
var requestsCount = 1;
function makeRequest(i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://urlthatdoessomething.xxx",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (output_string) {
            $('#results').append('<p class=\"normal-msg\">' + inputValue[i] + 
              ' column successfully converted...</p> ');
            if (requestsCount < inputValue.length) {
                makeRequest(requestsCount + 1);
                requestsCount ++;
            }
        },
        error: function (output_string) {
            $('#results').append('<p class=\"error-msg\">
               ERROR:  Check spelling and try again... </p> ');
        }
    });
}
makeRequest(inputValue[1]);
```

Side note: the above is a translation of your code.  You might have meant to write `var i = 0` in your for loop, as arrays are zero indexed.  If that's the case, change `var requestsCount = 1;` to `var requestsCount = 0;` and `makeRequest(inputValue[1]);` to `makeRequest(inputValue[0]);`.

Comment: @dsiler12221 - Thanks.  Yes, as I am disregarding the first input field in the form, I started the iteration at 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  If so could you mark it as the answer?  If not, what can I help you with?